# Iterative sliced indexing (python) starting form the end : how to avoid "-0" to be equal to "0"?

Tags: python, indexing, slice

I have a list (actually a pandas.DataFrame, but let's make it simple), let's say:

```
a = list(range(10))
```

I have to iterate on it and extract at each loop all the element from the beginning up to a "moving end". I want the whole list at the first iteration, drop the last element at the second iteration, drop the two last elements at third...and so on.

It seemed easy to code:

```
for i in range(5) :
    print(i,a[:-i])
```

In fact this code works fine from "1" and later. But for i=0 I get an empty list, while I would like to get the full list.

I understand than "-0" is equal to "0" and that's why I am having this behaviour...but is there anything I could do about that?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it just doesn't that work that way.  You can do the moving end up through [:-1], and then you have to do the whole list separately.

Comment: you can use [cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for continued list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the ending index explicitly:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, a[: len(a) - i])
```

Or replace the end index with `None` when at zero:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, a[: -i or None])
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how to deal with it, by adding to the negative indexed end the list length :

```
for i in range(5) :
    print(i,a[:len(a)-i])
```

This modification produces the whole list at the first iteration (desired result).